# Cache controller with json response

Tags: 8, caching, page-controller

I want to return a cached response in a controller that returns JSON data. I tried the following code.

```php
$build = array(
  '#cache' => array(
    'contexts' => ['ip'],
  ),
);

return (new CacheableJsonResponse(['test'], 200))->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($build));
```

I get this exception.

> LogicException: The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you are not rendering content too early. Returned object class: Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableJsonResponse. in Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext() (line 154 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/finder-cms/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php).

Answer (score 10):

The controller from your question runs without exception:

```
public function demo() {
  $build = [
    '#cache' => [
      'contexts' => ['ip'],
    ],
  ];
  return (new CacheableJsonResponse(['test'], 200))->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($build));
}
```

Result:

> ["test"]

To produce the exception you need a controller like this:

```
public function demo() {

  $build = ['#markup' => 'early rendering'];
  $markup = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($build);

  $build = [
    '#cache' => [
      'contexts' => ['ip'],
    ],
  ];
  return (new CacheableJsonResponse(['test'], 200))->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($build));
}
```

Result:

> LogicException: The controller result claims to be providing relevant
> cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you
> are not rendering content too early.

This may not always be that obvious. Another example is when you try to get an url from an url object, see this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/187094/47547

---

**Add an URL with cacheable metadata to a response**

This is how you avoid the exception, when you render an url for a json response, and at the same time add the correct cache metadata to the response:

```
  $generated_url = $url->toString(TRUE);
  $response = new CacheableJsonResponse(['url' => $generated_url->getGeneratedUrl()], 200);
  $response->addCacheableDependency($generated_url);
  return $response;
```

Comment: ! Ok i fixed: ->toString(TRUE)->getGeneratedUrl()
THZZ ::)

Comment: Why I Can not render html first to be able to put in a JSON example to be printed?

Comment: see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!EventSubscriber!EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php/class/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber/8.2.x

Comment: ok, is but url problem a bug? Becouse this generate bug also in twig function like: path() or url(). I have a fixed when a custom function twig :(

Comment: This is not a bug, this is used in twig to get cache metadata. You should do the same, add the url as cacheable dependency to the response.

Comment: how can I do ? " add the url as cacheable dependency to the response"

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score -2):

After using multiple options, below code worked in my case for returning rest response.

```
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', [
  'node' => $node->id(),
], $options);
$url = $url->toString(true)->getGeneratedUrl();
```

Cheers!

Comment: Why is this comment downvoted?