# Is there a way to apply cached access results to listings?

Tags: views, entities, caching

Code that is put in either hook_entity_access or an access handler has no effect on listings such as views field displays and search. I am not sure if this is by design or due to an error from my side, but my guess is that the db queries don't have a way to factor in the generated then cached access results.

This bit I mean:

```
return AccessResult::forbidden()->cachePerPermissions()->cachePerUser()->addCacheableDependency($stuff);
```

Is there a way to factor it in listings? If not how should I go about applying the same logic in hook_entity_access or access handlers to listings?

Comment: Can you see a relevant cache context in the `X-Drupal-Cache-Contexts` response header for the listing? You may also be able to alter the views query to apply access control.( https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.8.x ) That way you could vary the result and cache context for the user.

Comment: I haven't had e a use for this before. Are these the ones listed under the main document/page?
Query can do it, yes. Is that different from using entity queryAccess handler?

Comment: Entity queries don't have a way to pass cache metadata. They just bubble it up, which is OK when used in a render context but can cause problems when not. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251864/logicexception-the-controller-result-claims-to-be-providing-relevant-cache-meta

Comment: Is the better solution then to save the calculated access results to DB and alter queries to reflect the correct outcome? 4k4 is this more related to this https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2876258

Comment: The solution you describe is basically how Drupal implements node grants saving the access results in the table `node_access` and altering the node query in [node_query_node_access_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_query_node_access_alter/9.2.x).

Comment: I know. It seems like the simplest solution but not sure if it is the correct one. See this: https://www.drupal.org/project/group/issues/3162259
There is mention of an entity system in #12, so, I am trying to piece together how to make use of that.

Comment: This is in Group's Query Access class:
Group and Cart I think do it with QueryAccess. There is this comment in Group's QueryAccess class:
With sites that have
 * thousands or more grouped entities, this is not sustainable. Instead we alter
 * the query directly to join the group_content_field_data table.

Does that mean that altering queries for smaller sites is sufficient with an event dispatcher/listener  but not for bigger ones? I'd like to know why is it not sustainable. Is joining tables always the better alternative?