# Entity access handler causing "The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected."

Tags: entities, 9

I'm writing a custom entity access handler for a custom entity that checks if a user has access to the underlying node. The checkAccess() code looks like this:

```
$uuid = $entity->uuid->getString();
if (isset($uuid)) {
  $nodes = $this->node->getQuery()->accessCheck(TRUE)->condition('uuid', $uuid)->execute();
  if (!empty($nodes)) {
    return AccessResult::allowed();
  }
}
return AccessResult::forbidden("Access denied.");
```

The problem is when I go to the jsonapi endpoint for the entity, I'm getting the error "`The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you are not rendering content too early. Returned object class: Drupal\\jsonapi\\CacheableResourceResponse.`"

If I return accessResult::allowed() before the $nodes query it works. What's happening here?

Comment: accessCheck(TRUE) leaks metadata, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251864/logicexception-the-controller-result-claims-to-be-providing-relevant-cache-meta. Why not use $entity->access('view')?

Comment: Looks like if I load the node and then do $node->access('view') it works, will post that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

It looks like using accessCheck(TRUE) causes this, so the workaround is:

```
if (isset($uuid)) {
  $node = $this->node->loadByProperties(['uuid' => $uuid]);
  $node = reset($action);
  if ($node->access('view')) {
    return AccessResult::allowed();
  }
}
```