# how to add cache tag in custom rss feed

Tags: 8, feeds

how to add cache tag in custom RSS feed in Drupal 8 
I have tried like this

```
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    $response = new Response();
    $xml_content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/">
      <channel>
       <title><![CDATA[ Title there ]]></title>
       <link><![CDATA[ siteurl.com ]]></link>
       <description><![CDATA[ description there ]]></description>
      </channel>
     </rss>';
    $cacheTags = ['node:nid', 'node:nid']
    $response->setContent($xml_content);
    $response->setCache(['etag' => $cacheTags]);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'xml');
```

but it not working

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  We try to answer knowledge base questions here. So far you've only stated various facts and haven't asked an explicit question. We need an **answerable question** to be asked. We aren't a "debug your site" service where we're going to ask you many questions about what you need to do to fix your site.

Answer (score 3):

Add the cache tags to the cacheable metadata of a cacheable response:

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableResponse;

  $response = new CacheableResponse();
  // ...
  $response->getCacheableMetadata()->addCacheTags(['node:nid', 'node:nid']);
```

Comment: LogicException: The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you are not rendering content too early. Returned object class: Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableResponse

Comment: Different issue and not caused by the code of your question, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225956/cache-controller-with-json-response