# How to redirect to content if view have 1 result?

Tags: views, 8

Views page show content.
How to redirect to content page if views has only one result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme's **themename.theme** file add:

At the very top add:

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
```

Then add:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render()
 */
function THEMENAME_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
    if($view->id() == "view_name" && $view->current_display == 'view_machine_name') {
      if (!empty($view->result) && count($view->result) == 1) {
        $url = $view->result[0]->_entity->toUrl()->toString();
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        $response->send();
      }
    }
}
```

Clear the cache so changes kick in.

---

my_module/src/Controller/**ViewPageController.php**

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableRedirectResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\views\Views;

/**
 * Defines HelloController class.
 */
class ViewPageController extends ControllerBase {

  public function content() {

    $view = Views::getView('view_name');
    $view->setDisplay('view_machine_name');
    $view->execute();

    if (!empty($view->result) && count($view->result) == 1) {

      $url = $view->result[0]->_entity->toUrl()->toString(TRUE);
      $response = new CacheableRedirectResponse($url->getGeneratedUrl());
      $response->getCacheableMetadata()->addCacheTags($view->getCacheTags());
      $response->addCacheableDependency($url);
      return $response;

    }
    else {

      return [
        '#type' => 'view',
        '#name' => 'view_name',
        '#view' => $view,
        '#display_id' => 'view_machine_name',
        '#embed' => TRUE,
        '#cache' => $view->getCacheTags(),
      ];

    }

  }

}
```

This is the [view_machine_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsMjX.jpg).

Comment: You need to clear the cache every time ;-). It's never a good idea to send a response instead of returning it. But for this use case when a redirect depends on database content I think a custom controller which either returns the view or a cacheable redirect response containing the correct cache metadata would be the best approach.

Comment: @4k4 `You need to clear the cache every time` Doesn't the view get invalidated via cache tag? Or are you referring to when adding a new hook?

Comment: Yes, but the redirect needs to get invalidated, too, when the view result is no longer 1. The problem with sending is you have to responses, one you've sent and one which is getting cached, which makes this quite unpredictable what happens.

Comment: @4k4 you're right, I could've sworn it worked for me without having to clear the cache, but now it won't work unless I clear the cache. Oh I see now, I prob got a false positive due to having multiple view blocks on the page. I didn't do a view_name conditional.

Comment: @4k4 I thought of custom controller at first, but was too lazy for that. So I tried to see if there was quicker alternative.

Comment: @4k4 this seems to work fine, tho I am not sure if that's the proper way to return the response, as I'm suppose to be returning an array. I couldn't find a [RenderElement](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements) that would fit the bill for this.

Comment: Yes, a controller can return a response, but use a CacheableRedirectResponse and add the cache tags: `$response->getCacheableMetadata()->addCacheTags($view->getCacheTags());`. The 
OP might also need to add more cache data, the question doesn't provide any details on which the result might depend on.

Comment: @4k4 `getCacheableMetadata()` is not a valid method for [RedirectResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21RedirectResponse.php/class/RedirectResponse/8.2.x). Anyhow, I did a `$response->isCacheable();` and it came back false, so we good.

Comment: The problem is that Drupal still caches the uncacheable RedirectResponse, then without cache tags. Only if you use [CacheableRedirectResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cache%21CacheableRedirectResponse.php/class/CacheableRedirectResponse/8.7.x) and add the cache tags it will get invalidated when the content changes in the database.

Comment: @4k4 Using CacheableRedirectResponse [gave an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXr2z.png) `The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you are not rendering content too early. Returned object class: Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata. in Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber...` clearing the cache does not fix it.

Comment: Yes, this is another tricky one. When you convert a URL to a string use `toString(TRUE)` and add the resulting cache dependency to the response as well, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225956/cache-controller-with-json-response

Comment: @4k4 when using `TRUE` you need `->getGeneratedUrl();` after it; otherwise, it throws an error. Cheers!

Comment: @NoSssweat I just reverted that edit (you missed the line immediately after, which uses `$generated_url->getGeneratedUrl()`)

Comment: No, `$response->addCacheableDependency($url);` doesn't work when this is already applied.

Comment: @4k4 sorry I'm a bit confused, 6 am here, you're talking about your [other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/225963/27710) that Clive reverted, right? OR are you saying I don't need that line here?

Comment: You need the line, but for $url without getGeneratedUrl() applied. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @4k4 ha, I fee like an idiot, time to go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a LOT better way. Use hook_views_post_render() instead. See my comment [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/8.6.x#comment-65765).

and the documentation at [views.api.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/9.4.x)

```
/**
 * Post-process any render data.
 *
 * The module or theme may add, modify or remove elements in $output after
 * rendering.
 *
 * If a module wishes to act on the rendered HTML of the view rather than the
 * structured content array, it may use this hook to add a #post_render
 * callback:
 * @code
 * // The object must implement \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface.
 * $output['#post_render'][] = '\Drupal\my_module\View::postRender';
 * @endcode
 *
 * See \Drupal\Core\Render\RendererInterface::render() for #post_render
 * documentation.
 *
 * Alternatively, it could also implement hook_preprocess_HOOK() for
 * the particular view template, if there is one.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view
 *   The view object being processed.
 * @param array $output
 *   A structured content array representing the view output. The given array
 *   depends on the style plugin and can be either a render array or an array of
 *   render arrays.
 * @param \Drupal\views\Plugin\views\cache\CachePluginBase $cache
 *   The cache settings.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable
 */
function hook_views_post_render(ViewExecutable $view, array &$output, CachePluginBase $cache) {

  // When using full pager, disable any time-based caching if there are fewer
  // than 10 results.
  if ($view->pager instanceof Drupal\views\Plugin\views\pager\Full && $cache instanceof Drupal\views\Plugin\views\cache\Time && count($view->result) options['results_lifespan'] = 0;
    $cache->options['output_lifespan'] = 0;
  }
}
```