# "LogicException: The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected."

Tags: 8, caching, page-controller

Hi I've created a module with a controller but now i'm getting this message;

The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you are not rendering content too early. Returned object class: Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableJsonResponse.

this is my code:

```
$cpdata=[];
$cpdata[]=[
  'image'=>'image.png',
  'title'=>'item01',
  'price'=>'30',
];

$cache_options['#cache'] = [
  'contexts' => ['url',],
  'tags' => ['node_list:Content']
];
$response = new CacheableJsonResponse($cpdata);
$response->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($cache_options));
return $response;
```

is some way to fix this issue?
I appreciate your help

Comment: The code seems to be incomplete as in  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225956/cache-controller-with-json-response

Comment: I take `$cpdata` isn't considered a render array because it doesn't contain any #-property.